# How create script with dynamic name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with clear cache in browsers.

I think that you need to generate scripts with dynamic unique name. How this to do?

Comment: This is not a real question. What have you tried so far? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess you mean this:

```
<script>document.write('<script src="script_path?' + Math.random() + '"\><\/script>');</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard practice is to add random query parameter to the script name. How to do so depend on a way you generate links to the script. One option is to add hash of the file as such cash busting query parameter - this way you will guarantee that new version is cached.

Alternatively you can put versioning in the path to script files (../v1234/script.js) but is may require more code to implement and complicates moving static files to CDN.

Note: be careful not to break debugging experience with cache busting - some browser will not recognize breakpoints on load if you use new Urls on every request.